# CentOS vs RedHat on hp DL 380 G5

Tags: centos, rhel, system-installation

hp [lists](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3288134&taskId=135&prodTypeId=5351&prodSeriesId=1121516&lang=en&cc=us) downloads for:

```
»   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 Server (x86)
»   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 Server (x86-64)
»   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Server (x86)
»   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Server (x86-64)
```

but only

```
»   CentOS 5
```

Since, as I understand it, CentOS is basically repackaged RHEL, is there any reason I shouldn't be able to run CentOS 6.4 x86_64 on an hp DL 380 G5, including running the management rpms meant for EL 6?  (I've come across threads about CentOS 6.2 having some issues, but not 6.4.)  (The management rpms are somewhat key since they would allow me to keep tabs on how the RAID array is functioning via a script, which is what I'm used to.)

Can anyone confirm success/trouble with 6.4 64-bit on a G5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 6.4 works fine, including RAID tool, no worries.

```
~ # dmidecode | grep ProLiant
        Product Name: ProLiant DL380 G5
        Family: ProLiant

~ # cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

~ # hpacucli ctrl all show
Smart Array P400 in Slot 1    (sn: ....)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now is that `hpacucli` for CentOS 5 or for EL 6?

Comment: Not sure, it's `hpacucli-8.75-12.0.i386` (although the OS is 64bit).